# Calling Tkinter Objects from Another File

Tags: python, tkinter, calling-convention

> ```
> class SneakerGuide(tk.Frame):
>
>     def __init__(self, parent, controller):
>         tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
>         
>         global stockXURLInput
>         stockXURLInput = Entry(sneakerBasicDetails)
>         stockXURLInput.grid(row=5, column=1)
> ```

So I have this class, and within it, I have this function that is an initialization function and withing that I have a bunch of different things I want to .get() from. I just typed out one example. But I am trying to get the entry input outside of that class (actually I am trying to get it from another file but I know how to import them and stuff. How would I go about doing that in this case in particular

Comment: If you want to access some variables inside a class, you need to create them as instance variables (prefix `self.`).  Then you can access them via the instance of the class, i.e. if `a` is the instance of `SneakerGuide`, use `a.somevar` to access the instance variable `somevar` of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For objects you want to access outside of the class, you must make them instance attributes of the class.

For example, you wouldn't use `global` like in your example. The use of `global` largely defeats the purpose of using classes. Instead, you do it like this:

```
class SneakerGuide(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        self.stockXURLInput = Entry(sneakerBasicDetails)
        self.stockXURLInput.grid(row=5, column=1)
```

To get the value out of the entry, all you need is a reference to the instance of the class.

```
root = tk.Tk()
...
guide = SneakerGuide(root)
...
print(f"The url is {guide.stockXURLInput.get9)}")
```

This isn't anything unique to tkinter, this is how all python objects work.

Comment: I did that and got errors saying: "Class 'SneakerGuide' has no 'stockXURLInput' member

Comment: @JohnSantoro: if that is the case, then you did it wrong. If python says the `guide` object doesn't have a `stockXURLInput` attribute, it's telling the truth. This is fundamental to how all python objects work.

Comment: Just to clarify, what would I put as the root in guide = SneakerGuide(root)

Comment: @JohnSantoro: the instance of `Tk` you should have created at the start of the program, or any other widget.

Comment: Awesome thanks! and also thanks for the quick reply! Since you are here, I have a really similar question I asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64811482/getting-nested-variables-in-init-function and no one answered it. I would be really thankful if you could. It is the same principals discussed here, just used in a different way