# Getting Nested Variables in __init__function

Tags: python, function, class, scope

Code:

class GmailFarming(tk.Frame):

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    def StartSeleniumScript():

        with open("json/Gmail_farming/Tasks/Tasks.json", "r") as f:
            tasksJsonFile = json.load(f)

            for task in tasksJsonFile['tasks']:
                if task['id'] == 1:

                    #Get info Needed from json

                    mode_chosen_to_run = task['mode_chosen']
                    account_chosen_to_run = task['account_chosen']

                    #Get account info from selected account

                    with open("json/Gmail_farming/Profiles/Profiles.json", "r") as acc:
                        accountsJsonFile = json.load(acc)

                        for account in accountsJsonFile['accounts']:
                            if account['id'] == 1:


                                email_for_account_to_run = account['email']
                                password_for_account_to_run = account['password']
```

Ok so I have this chunk of code and basically what I am trying to do is get the values of **email_for_account_to_run** and **password_for_account_to_run** (which are right at the bottom lines). I am having trouble doing so. I am trying to get those values from another file, but am kind of new to Python and am still confused about topics like this. Any help with how to get those values from pretty much outside of the GmailFarming class would be great! Thanks in advance, and PS, idk why the class isn't showing up in the code block, but it is the class, and then the def **init** indented under it!

Answer (score 0):

Reading your code, I assume what you are trying to do is creating a class with an `__init__` method that defines an auxiliary function `StartSeleniumScript` in which you declare two variables `email_for_account_to_run` and `password_for_account_to_run` from which you want to recover the values outside of the class.

At the least I find your code confusing because:

- you mix object-oriented style programming with functional style (instead you could have created an auxiliary method `startSeleniumScript(self)` at the same level as the `__init__` method rather than nesting a function definition inside it)
- the nested function you create is never even called
- the nested function you create has no `return` value
- the class has no instance variable declared in the `__init__` method
- you never create an instance of the class

All this leaves me a bit perplex as to what exactly you want to do but something like this would work:

```
class GmailFarming:
    
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        
        def StartSeleniumScript():
            self.foo = 1
            self.bar = 2
        
        StartSeleniumScript()
        
g = GmailFarming(None,None)
print(g.foo)
print(g.bar)
```

In essence, you add a `self.` in front of the variables that you would like to access so that they become instance variables that you can access from the outside. And of course you have to create an object of the class first before you can get the instance variables out of it.

Personally, I would have defined the nested function as an auxiliary method like this, however:

```
class GmailFarming:
    
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.__startSeleniumScript()
        
    def __startSeleniumScript(self):
        self.foo = 1
        self.bar = 2
    
g = GmailFarming(None,None)
print(g.foo)
print(g.bar)
```

Comment: Hi, so sorry for the confusion. I isolated only the part of the code I needed help with. I have a lot more code within the class and __init__ function I just chose to leave out so it is easier to view. I also had it set up where I just returned ``email_for_account_to_run`` and ``password_for_account_to_run`` and accessed it like that, but my main concern is what if I had a ton of values, like 20-30. I can't say return and type out every single value I wouldn't think. That seems like very inefficient code. So if I have something within layers of for loops and if statements, how can I access it?

Comment: you could create another class or use a dictionnary in which to store all the values, rather than accessing each of the variables separately