# How to run tkinter code from another module

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a module that needs to display a tkinter file dialog when a method in it is run. The code runs perfectly when I run the module directly. However, when I import the module and run the function from a separate module, it doesn't work.

This is the error I get:

```
2023-09-28 21:41:05.282 Python[5684:183920] -[SDLApplication macOSVersion]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155713af0
2023-09-28 21:41:05.284 Python[5684:183920] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SDLApplication macOSVersion]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155713af0'
```

This is the function that opens the file dialog:

```
def showFileGUI():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Tkinter Open File Dialog')
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.geometry('300x150')


    def select_file():
        filetypes = (
            ('text files', '*.txt'),
            ('All files', '*.*')
        )

        filename = fd.askopenfilename(
            title='Open a file',
            initialdir='/',
            filetypes=filetypes)

        showinfo(
            title='Selected File',
            message=filename
        )


    # open button
    open_button = ttk.Button(
        root,
        text='Open a File',
        command=select_file
    )

    open_button.pack(expand=True)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try looking at [Calling Tkinter Ibjects from Another File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64655107/calling-tkinter-objects-from-another-file).